# Не работает wp_mail?

Tags: php, wordpress, email, openserver

На локальном сервере Open Server, я отправляю письмо с помощь функции **mail** php.

Все работает:

```
<?php 
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);

require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../wp-load.php' );
$to = "you@yourdomain.com";
$subject = 'wp_mail function test';
$message = 'This is a test of the wp_mail function: wp_mail is working';

$sent_message = mail( $to, $subject, $message );

if ( $sent_message ) {
    echo 'success';
} else {
    echo 'error';
}?>
```

Возвращает: **SUCCESS**, и письмо приходит на локалку.

А вот на WordPress **wp_mail** возвращает: **ERROR**, и письмо не приходит:

```
<?php 
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);

require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../wp-load.php' );
$to = "you@yourdomain.com";
$subject = 'wp_mail function test';
$message = 'This is a test of the wp_mail function: wp_mail is working';

$sent_message = wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message );

if ( $sent_message ) {
    echo 'success';
} else {
    echo 'error';
}?>
```

Error

WordPress функции работают, а вот wp_mail нет?

В чем проблема?

Спасибо!!!

Comment: Непонятно зачем тут использовать  wp_mail.. Но всё равно укажи во from мыло на домене с которого отправляется почта. Для надёжности этот адрес стоит завести в ПУ хостинга.

Comment: код рабочий. у меня письмо отправляется.попробуй вызвать в 4-ом параметре $headers = 'From: My Name <myname@mydomain.com>' . "\r\n";

Comment: Спасибо, теперь работает!!!